# how to get rid of error C3861:?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class defined in c++. And I have a template inside its .h file. And this template few of the local classes defined in .cxx file.

contents of a.h

```
namespace test
{
 Class a
 {
   template<classT>
   {
     abc  xyz = //some initialization
   }
 };
}
```

contents of a.cxx

```
#include "a.h"
namespace test
{
   class abc 
   {
   };
}
```

when I compile this file it is compiled fine. But when I try to use the template that I defined in a.h . it throws me following error.

error C3861: 'abc': identifier not found

Comment: Why are you declaring abc in a.cxx? You should put that in a header file and load that before your template that uses it.

Comment: Why `class abc` is in `a.cxx` and not in the header file? And why the file extension is `cxx`, not `cpp`?

Comment: You need to put a big arrow pointing at the line of code in the snippet that doesn't compile.

Comment: This code will not compile. Post the correct code. What is `template<classT>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a forward declaration of abc class like:

```
namespace test
{

 class abc;

 class a
 {
   template<classT>
   {
     abc  xyz = //some initialization
   }
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you miss to put the declaration of `class abc` in the .h file.

And you put `Class a` instead of `class a`.